# How to Instantiate Kafka Connect Schema array

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

How do you instantiate an Array instance declared with [SchemaBuilder](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/SchemaBuilder.html).array(ARRAY_SCHEMA)?

With Kafka Connect Schema you can instantiate an [org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/Struct.html) in your custom connector like so:

```
Schema STRUCT_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct().field("timestamp", Schema.INT64_SCHEMA).build();
Struct s = new Struct(STRUCT_SCHEMA);
```

You can also declare an array schema, but I can't figure out how to create one:

```
Schema ARRAY_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.array(Schema.FLOAT64_SCHEMA).build();
// Create one here, how?
```

I'm actually trying to nest an array inside a struct, but I presume the problem is I can't instantiate an array instance.  Simply adding a native Java array doesn't seem to work.  The error I'm seeing at runtime is:

```
Unable to create Struct from value: org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Invalid Java object for schema type ARRAY: class [Ljava.lang.Double; for field: "floatValues"
```

For nested schema:

```
Schema ARRAY_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.array(Schema.OPTIONAL_FLOAT64_SCHEMA).optional().build();
Schema STRUCT_SCHEMA = SchemaBuilder.struct()
                .field("timestamp", Schema.INT64_SCHEMA)
                .field("floatValues", ARRAY_SCHEMA).build();
Struct s = new Struct(STRUCT_SCHEMA);
s.put("floatValues", new Double[]{Double.valueOf(1)});
// I assume I must need to wrap the Double[] inside some Kafka Connect Array object?
```

Resources I've reviewed:

- [Apache Connect Documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#connect)
- [Apache Connect javadoc](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/package-summary.html)
- [Confluent Connector Developer Guide](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/devguide.html)
- [Expert R. Moffatt's Blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-converters-serialization-explained/)
- [Confluent Hub (browsing source code of random open source connectors)](https://www.confluent.io/hub/)

Comment: Did you try a `Float[]`?

Comment: Using Float[] results in similar error message at runtime just substitute "class [Ljava.lang.Double;"  with "class [Ljava.lang.Float;"

Comment: How about a `List<Double>`?

Comment: Might be getting closer.  Using a  List<Double> results in `Invalid Java object for schema type FLOAT64: class java.lang.Float for field: "null"`

Comment: Actually, using a  List<Double> works.   Using a  List<Float> results in `Invalid Java object for schema type FLOAT64: class java.lang.Float for field: "null"`   Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a  `java.util.Collection` implementation, such as ArrayList or LinkedList

You can see the `Struct` [unit tests here](https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/connect/api/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/connect/data/StructTest.java#L95-L98)

Comment: This implies that the performance of Connect will be poor for messages containing a large array of bytes (or any native type) - since you have to box up the array into a List.   Kind-of the oppose of the zero-copy here.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. An arraylist has an internal array. Elements don't need copied between two collections. Kafka records are already "large array of bytes", the Struct class just defines a format to them

Comment: Two years later!  Anyways I was referring to fact that Java Collections cannot contain primitives (only wrapper Objects).   I haven't checked up on this, but from a naive perspective it seems like performance is going to be worse if you must wrap your byte[] into an ArrayList<Byte>.  Who knows, maybe Java does some cool trick here.  No biggie.

Comment: Haha! I found the unanswered comment after searching myself for this issue since I'd forgotten how to write a unit test with an array schema. I've not tested with array around `Schema.BYTES_SCHEMA`